# Sequelize join data in tree

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have 3 models that work like a tree: Plants, Genre and family.

Each family can have a lot of genres each genre is associated to 1 family.

Same for Genre, each 1 can have a lot of plants and 1 plant can have 1 genre.

So based on that, i have this models:

**Plant**

```
"use strict";
var sequelize = require('./index');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var User = require('./User');


module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Plant = sequelize.define("Plant", {
    specie: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    description: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: true,
      defaultValue: "No description for this plant yet"
    },
    directory: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
     genreId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true
    }
  },
    {
      associate: function (models) {
        Plant.hasMany(models.Foto, { foreignKey: "plantId", as: 'fotos' });
      }
    }
  );
```

**Genre**

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Genre = sequelize.define("Genre", {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    familyId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true
    },
    directory: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
  },
    {
      associate: function (models) {
        Genre.hasMany(models.Plant, { foreignKey: "genreId", as: 'plant' });
      }
    }
  );
```

**Family**

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Family = sequelize.define("Family", {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
      directory: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      }
  },
    {
      associate: function (models) {
        Family.hasMany(models.Genre, { foreignKey: "familyId", as: 'genre' });
      }
    }
  );
```

now, i do a query where i want to get all data related to the plant(genre and family) so i pass the id for the plant in the routing, via req.params.id.

after that i try to do a include so i can get the data with eager loading, because i need to get a json with all the data related to the plant.

But i can't get any data related to the other models, just with the specific plant table, any help?

**Here is the controller code on the server:**

```
specificPlant: function (req, res, next) {
        Plant.findAll({
            where: {
                id: req.params.id,
            },
            include: [{ all: true }] 

        }).then(function (plant) {
            console.log(plant);
            return res.send(plant);
        }).catch(function (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({ message: err.stack }); // 
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, define associations that will allow you to get data Plant->Genre->Family

```
Plant.hasMany(models.Genre, {foreignKey: "genreId", as: 'genre' });
Genre.hasMany(models.Family, { foreignKey: "familyId", as: 'family' });
```

Then you can query

```
    Plant.findAll({
        where: {
            id: req.params.id,
        },
        include: [{
            model: Genre,
            as: 'genre',
            include: [{
                model: Family,
                as: 'family'
            }]
        }]
    }).then(function (plant) {
        //plant
        //plant.genre
        //plant.genre.family
    });
```

Comment: Isn't it Family.hasMany(Genres) and Genre.hasMany(Plant)?

Comment: No, hasMany relation allows you to query Family->Genres, in your case you need to query reverse Genres->Family

Comment: so instead of using hasmany, can't i use belongToo? because it doesn't make sense 1 genre has more then 1 family :S

Comment: Don't delete existed relations, just add new belongsTo associations into models

Comment: thank you, can you help me with this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44303078/sequelize-join-data-in-tree/44305011?noredirect=1#comment75616036_44305011